# Check if restaurant sells only the pizzas that customer likes using SQL

Tags: postgresql

Tables for SQL query

**1. Likes(cname, pizza)**

**2. Customers(cname, area)**

**3. Restaurants(rname, area)**

**4. Sells (rname, pizza, price)**

**Condition:**

1. Customer likes all the pizza in the restaurant
2. Restaurant has the same location as customer

Result: List of customers that fulfill the conditions

**My attempt:**

```
    SELECT DISTINCT Customer (
    FROM Sells S, Likes L, Restaurant R, Customer C
    WHERE C.area = R.area     -- Check whether location of customer = restaurant
    AND L.pizza = S.pizza     -- But i'm not clear how to check if the restaurant sells only the pizzas that the particular customer likes. 
    );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd logically do (2) first with a join ("Restaurant has the same location as customer"), and then eliminate the results with a restaurant that sells a pizza that the customer doesn't like:

> ```
> create table customers(
>   cname text
>  ,area text
> );
>
> insert into customers(cname,area)
> values('alice', 'east')
>      ,('bob', 'north')
>      ,('james', 'central');
>
> create table restaurants(
>   rname text
>  ,area text
> );
>
> insert into restaurants(rname,area)
> values('Pizza Place', 'east')
>      ,('Pizza Local', 'west')
>      ,('Pizza World', 'central');
>
> create table sells(
>   rname text
>  ,pizza text
>  ,price int
> );
>
> insert into sells(rname,pizza,price)
> values('Pizza Place', 'hawaiian','10'),
>   ('Pizza Local', 'pepperoni','11'),
>   ('Pizza World', 'chicken','12'),
>   ('Pizza World', 'meat feast','13'),
>   ('Pizza World', 'veggie','8');
>
> create table likes(
>   cname text
>  ,pizza text
> );
>
> insert into likes(cname,pizza)
> values ('alice', 'hawaiian')
>       ,('bob', 'pepperoni')
>       ,('james', 'chicken')
>       ,('james', 'meat feast');
> ```

> ```
> select *
> from customers c join restaurants r using (area)
> where not exists( select pizza from sells where rname=r.rname
>                   except
>                   select pizza from likes where cname=c.cname );
> ```
>
> ```
> area | cname | rname      
> :--- | :---- | :----------
> east | alice | Pizza Place
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=c97cf96c15f4219e7a358487ea72d374)*

To get the list of customers just change `select *` to `select distinct cname`

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
select c. Cname
    From
Customers c
    Join
Restaurant r on c.area= r.area --check that restaurant is closest
    Join
 Sells s on s.rname = r.rname 
    Left outer Join
 Likes l on c.cname=l.cname and l.pizza = s.pizza
    Group by c.cname
Having sum(case when l.cname is null then 1 else 0 end) =  0
```

The last line counts how many customers like pizzas that can't be matched to ones the restaurant sells.

EDIT;
Updated the filter to check that all of the pizzas that the restaurant sells are liked by the customer. Link to SQL fiddle; http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d5cf74/4/0